# reading a graph from file

Tags: c++, graph, fileinputstream

i am doing an assignment in which i have to implement dijkstra's algorithm for an undirected graph.i have to read a graph from the text file. i have implemented the following function:

```
graph :: graph()
{
    ifstream fe("adj.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        mat[i][j]=0;
    }
    string str;
    while(getline(fe,str))
    {

        istringstream ss(str);
        int node,i;
        ss>>node;
        while(ss>>i)
        mat[node-1][i-1]=1;
    }
}
```

mat is the 2-d array and size is the number of nodes.

the file is in the form adjacency list.the first number in the line represents the node and the numbers after that represents the nodes adjacent to the node.

mat is the 2-d array and size is the number of nodes.
it function works fine for small number of vertices but as i increase the size(200), and try to print the graph(in the form a matrix), the printing doesn't starts from the first node(in my case it starts from 116th vertex).
how can i make it work for large size graph?

EDIT: i am using a simple double loop for printing the graph.

```
void graph:: printgraph()
{
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {

            cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing obvious wrong with the code reading the file (if the values/indexes you read are 1-based), so maybe it's a problem with the printing? Or something else? How do you print the graph?

Comment: i am using a double loop for printing.

Comment: What is the format of the input data?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines were causing the issue?

Comment: FIrst, nothing wrong.  But when you print all this data:  are you sure that the first lines are not simply lost by scroling of terminal ?

Comment: @user3234651 I hate to do this but I think that we need to see the input because it's very likely a problem with the input.